# Can a combo box be ready for typed input as soon as the form it is in opens?

Tags: combobox, onload

The main form of a Microsoft Access application has a combo box as the first field with focus in it's first and main form. I would like for users to be able to start typing into the combo box without having to click on it first. Is this possible? What VBA code would accomplish this?

I already have cboCaseName.SetFocus at the end of the Form_Load() sub. That doesn't do it.